# 'The sku 'ElasticPool' specified is invalid' with New-AzSqlDatabaseCopy

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-powershell, azure-elasticpool

I'm trying to convert from `New-AzureRmSqlDatabaseCopy` to `New-AzSqlDatabaseCopy`, but I'm getting an error when trying to copy a database to the same server:

> Microsoft.Rest.Azure.CloudException: Long running operation failed
> with status 'Failed'. Additional Info:'The sku 'ElasticPool' specified
> is invalid.'

```
New-AzSqlDatabaseCopy `
       -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName `
       -ServerName $serverName `
       -DatabaseName $templateDbName `
       -CopyDatabaseName $newDbName `
       -CopyServerName $serverName `
       -CopyResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName
```

The database copies successfully when using `New-AzureRmSqlDatabaseCopy`, I can't figure why `New-AzSqlDatabaseCopy` would be different.  I've tried specifying the `-ElasticPoolName` and `-ServiceObjectName` parameters, but no luck.

I don't know if this is relevant, but I'm running the PowerShell from an Azure runbook.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the new Elastic Pool has the same name and as the old Elastic Pool. Also make sure the SKU are same for both the elastic pools. If the resource groups are in different regions, the SKU (Standard?) for elastic pools may differ causing issues while copying the database.

Comment: I'm trying to create the copy in the same resource group, same server, and same elastic pool as the original database.  So it shouldn't be a different region or SKU, I think?

Comment: New-AzSqlDatabaseCopy -CopyDatabaseName demodatabase_QA -CopyResourceGroupName "demo-rg"-CopyServerName demoazuresql01-DatabaseName demodatabase -ResourceGroupName "demo-rg" -ServerName demoazuresql01

Comment: Something like this should work